# Vaadin Compile widgets (addons) in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, compilation, widget, vaadin

I'm following the [provided instructions](https://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons/netbeans) but is not working. I'm getting this error:

```
INFO: Widgetsets found from classpath:
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:Z:/vaadin/vaadin-6.7.1.jar!/
org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextmenuWidgetset in jar:file:Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/2.01.xx/XincoLibs/ContextMenu3.1.0.jar!/

getAvailableWidgetSets
INFO: Search took 12ms
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume     label syntax is incorrect
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:589)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.WidgetSetBuilder.updateWidgetSet(WidgetSetBuilder.java:79)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.WidgetSetBuilder.main(WidgetSetBuilder.java:52)
```

I found a [related bug](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/5562) but it's been reported for a long time without fix yet. Any ideas besides checking/modifying the code myself?

**Edit:** Looking closer at the output I noticed this errors:

```
Compiling module org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextmenuWidgetset
Validating newly compiled units
  [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/Vaadin%20Addons/ContextMenu3-1-0/org/vaadin/peter/contextmenu/client/ui/VContextMenu.java'
     [ERROR] Line 1: The declared package "org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.client.ui" does not match the expected package "ContextMenu3-1-0.org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.client.ui"
     [ERROR] Line 5: The import org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.client cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 125: VMenuItem cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 174: VMenuItem cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/Vaadin%20Addons/ContextMenu3-1-0/org/vaadin/peter/contextmenu/client/ui/VMenu.java'
     [ERROR] Line 1: The declared package "org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.client.ui" does not match the expected package "ContextMenu3-1-0.org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.client.ui"
     [ERROR] Line 219: The method itemClicked(VMenuItem) from the type VContextMenu refers to the missing type VMenuItem
     [ERROR] Line 229: The method itemClicked(VMenuItem) from the type VContextMenu refers to the missing type VMenuItem
     [ERROR] Line 239: The method itemClicked(VMenuItem) from the type VContextMenu refers to the missing type VMenuItem
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorDriver.java'
     [ERROR] Line 20: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 97: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/AbstractSimpleBeanEditorDriver.java'
     [ERROR] Line 28: Name clash: The method setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type BaseEditorDriver<T,E> has the same erasure as setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type EditorDriver<T> but does not override it
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/BaseEditorDriver.java'
     [ERROR] Line 31: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 67: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/SimpleViolation.java'
     [ERROR] Line 25: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 40: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 43: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 44: Missing code implementation in the compiler
     [ERROR] Line 49: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 49: Missing code implementation in the compiler
     [ERROR] Line 70: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 72: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 73: ConstraintViolation<?> cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 77: ConstraintViolation<capture#2-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 81: ConstraintViolation<capture#3-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 89: ConstraintViolation<capture#4-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 93: ConstraintViolation<capture#5-of ?> cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 98: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/testing/MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver.java'
     [ERROR] Line 26: The import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 35: The type MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver<T,E> must implement the inherited abstract method EditorDriver<T>.setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>)
     [ERROR] Line 107: Name clash: The method setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver<T,E> has the same erasure as setConstraintViolations(Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) of type EditorDriver<T> but does not override it
     [ERROR] Line 108: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/Configuration.java'
     [ERROR] Line 93: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 105: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 182: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 182: No source code is available for type TraversableResolver; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [ERROR] Line 194: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 194: No source code is available for type ConstraintValidatorFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [ERROR] Line 202: ValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 202: No source code is available for type ValidatorFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException_CustomFieldSerializer.java'
     [ERROR] Line 30: ConstraintViolationException cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 34: ConstraintViolationException cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 34: No source code is available for type ConstraintViolationException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
     [ERROR] Line 39: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 39: ConstraintViolation cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 40: ConstraintViolationException cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 44: ConstraintViolationException cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/MessageInterpolator.java'
     [ERROR] Line 21: The import javax.validation.metadata cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 66: ConstraintDescriptor cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.java'
     [ERROR] Line 30: The import javax.validation.Constraint cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 31: The import javax.validation.Payload cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 49: Constraint cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 49: The attribute validatedBy is undefined for the annotation type Constraint
     [ERROR] Line 75: Payload cannot be resolved to a type
  [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Z:/NetBeans/Xinco/3.00.xx/XincoLibs/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/spi/ConfigurationState.java'
     [ERROR] Line 22: The import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 24: The import javax.validation.TraversableResolver cannot be resolved
     [ERROR] Line 93: ConstraintValidatorFactory cannot be resolved to a type
     [ERROR] Line 107: TraversableResolver cannot be resolved to a type
```

I found this post about this issue pointing out to be a library mismatch but I'm using jars from the Vaadin SCM for the correct release: https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/384826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Issue](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/5562) finally fixed, hopefully that does the trick. After that had to add the following jars to the project so it could be compiled:

1. validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
2. validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar

Comment: My project didn't compile. It's throwing java.io.IOException: Could not create directory for the widgetset: file: E:\Projetos\smarthome\view\lib\vaadin-6.7.3.nightly-20111128-c22151.jar!\com\vaadin\terminal\gwt

Comment: Hmmm. I tried with the released 6.7.2. Unless you need a feature on 6.7.3 stick to the released version. If you do need it make sure to update your GTW files with the ones on the daily distro.

Comment: Did you have include these jars via Maven? I'll try with 6.7.2.

Comment: I was not using Maven, for Maven look here: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20Vaadin%20with%20Maven

Comment: Actually, I'm using SBT with Scala and Intellij.

Comment: Not sure if they support Intellij. The script is custom for NetBeans provided by them. Check this link for IntelliJ setup: https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/191680